# How to publish a layer with standalone geowebchache in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, curl

I have a multiple geoservers on two different systems with same port(one is backup for another) and geowebcache in on of the system with different port . Now i want to publish my layers in  geoserver with  standalone geowebcache. is there any material to refer? Please help me?

Comment: can you clarify your question? do you have some sort of load balancer that handles the two geoservers?